# Git merge driver script to automatically resolve merge conflict at specific line

Tags: git, git-merge, git-config, gitattributes

I have set up a Git merge driver that handles the merge for my base.html template, but I am not sure how to create the script that runs when that merge happens. I want the script to check if there is a merge conflict at a specific line. If there is, I want it to take the local version of the change. If there are other merge conflicts in that file though, I don't want those to be touched.

Comment: How do you expect to identify that line? Is it based on a fixed line number, a text pattern within the line itself, or from surrounding lines only?

Comment: @JeffBowman a text pattern.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/Praqma/git-merge-driver, its a decent example with a few other SO links that may help you out, provided you're already familiar with simple bash scripting

Comment: On second thought, the above link may not be perfect; I'm not quite sure how you only invoke your driver on your specific text pattern, or how your merge driver could fail otherwise. If you can figure out how to fail merging in your driver, then presumably you could just check for your pattern, resolve it, or fail if your pattern didn't match.